# Is there a way to use the REPLACE function in a TO_DATE function in SQL HANA

Tags: sql, hana

SELECT ADD_MONTHS (TO_DATE(REPLACE('6/23/17','/', '-'), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1) "add months" FROM DUMMY;

If I execute just the replace portion I get the date in the correct format with '-' instead of '/'

but when I try to use both functions together it fails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to replace: just use the relevant format specifier for your date string:

```
select add_months(to_date('6/23/17', 'mm/dd/yy'), 1) new_date
from dummy
```